# How do I print how many times a user entered something? Y out of X in "C."

Tags: c

For example, lets say I want to figure out how many users can receive SS.

```
int age = 0;
printf("Enter you all's ages, when finished, type - 1\n");
while (age != -1) {
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age >= 65)
        printf("X out of Y meet SS' age requirements")
}
```

Where `X` is how many users entered a number `>= 65`, and `Y` is the total amount of numbers entered other than `-1`. How do I do this?

I just noticed a flaw in my code also. Instead of printing the last print statement after the first user enters and `age >= 65`, it would have to be after the program is done. (After `-1` is printed)

Answer (score 1):

```
int age = 0;
int over = 0;
int total = 0;
printf("Enter you all's ages, when finished, type -1\n");
while (age != -1){
    scanf("%d", &age);
    if (age >= 65){
        over++;
    }
    total++;
    printf("%d out of %d meet SS' age requirements", over, total);
}
```

Comment: make it a do-while loop so that it doesn't add the -1

Comment: I ended up just starting from -1 and not 0, hope my shortcut isn't frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a counter to count how many people pass the age limit
so you need to declare a new variable, let say ,int counter,
where you have the print line, it should go counter++;

I dont know C so i cant write the code for you :)